# Save Entire Workbook as PDF Excel 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, excel

Is there anyway to save you entire workbook as a pdf in excel. I found this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407651(v=office.12).aspx, but it does not exactly tell you if it saves the entire workbook as a pdf or just the active sheet. If there is no way to save the entire workbook to pdf, would printing the entire workbook be the best option, or even possible in C#? Below is what I have thus far I just need it to save as pdf so I can send in an email. Thanks for the help.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //Excel Reference

//Gets Excel and gets Activeworkbook and worksheet

Excel.Application oXL;
Excel.Workbook oWB;
Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

//Create New Instance in Excel
oXL = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;

//Open Excel Workbook
oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("");
oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

//Modify Excel Spreadsheet Based on Form
oSheet.Cells[6, 4] = maskedTextBox1.Text; //Change Value in Cell, Cell Location [y-axis, x-axis]

//Save Workbook As
oWB.SaveAs("");

//Save Workbook As PDF


//Close Workbook
oWB.Close("");

//Quit Excel
oXL.Quit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2010 you can save the entire workbook in PDF by making each sheet an "Active" sheet.
Sounds strange but if you notice the print options when you do a pdf there is no option for workbook.  To get around this open an excel file and fill in some data in 2-3 work sheets.  Now hold your `ctrl` key and click on each other workbook, it will then become a "Group".

You will notice the `[GROUP]` name appear at the top of the excel file and now when you print the excel file it will print the entire workbook.

Try this out for yourself.  In code, you just need to make each work sheet an active worksheet.  I don't work much with the excel object model but it might be worth doing a macro for this and looking at the code.

I recorded a macro and here is the VBA:

`Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select`

Looks as though you just need to store each sheet in an array and then simply

`Sheets(MyArray).Select`

This will then make all sheets active and [grouped] and then you can run a print out to pdf.  By recording the macro it also presented the options to print to pdf:

```
`ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True`
```

In this case active sheet is your group of sheets that you have stored in an array.

Comment: Haha I ran the same thing hmm kk I think coverting is probably the best route Thank you

Comment: Russell Saari - to verify this simply open up excel and do this manually, you will see what happens.  If you dont make all sheets active the code will only print out the first sheet (active one).  You need to ensure you use the ctrl key and click on each sheet, doing so then look at the top of the excel file (the name area) will change to `[group]` and then save as pdf.

Comment: Thank you I will mark yours as correct I almost have it done I will post in your answer if that is ok?\

Comment: @RussellSaari - that's fine just glad to help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat.aspx