# Can I save an xslt (xml control output) as a pdf in vb.net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xslt, pdf

I want to save what a user is seeing on screen as a pdf file. I am using an xml control and the user is looking at the output of an xslt all nicely formatted the way I want it to look on the pdf. I would rather not purchase any 3rd party controls, though any suggestions will be marked as answer if they do solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just save the output XML?  It will view in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FO.net is a .net implementation of XSL-FO formatting objects (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects). http://fonet.codeplex.com/.
My team use this to generate PDF output from XML in a .net application.

Comment: thanks hamish! i am going to work with this today (or early next week). i will come back and mark as answer, it looks like exactly what i am looking for, i just want to see it in action.

Comment: We were exactly the same, after one of our guys wrote some automated tests and ran the library through it's paces we were sold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interop.PDFActiveX.dll to Save the Excel file as PDF

or

You can **[REFERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906722/save-entire-workbook-as-pdf-excel-2010-c)**

Comment: thanks, but i am not working with an excel file, i am working with XML and XSLT.