# Convert a file Excel (that is not saved) to PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

In my project, I have libraries PDFCreator end Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
I would like save a file PDF, from a file Excel. I saw many examples but in each example I found, it is about **Opening** an existing file Excel then convert it to PDF.

In my case, I create a file Excel **without saving it** (it is'nt supposed be saving) then I should save the created file Excel in PDF.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use Excel Interop to save the file directly to pdf (one link you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906722/save-entire-workbook-as-pdf-excel-2010-c). In any case, without saving the given file, no changes will be stored in the hard drive and thus no external program/library will be able to access what you did via interop. If you want to use any other library, you would have to save it.

Comment: You could always generate the PDF manually based on the data in the Excel file. That said, this will both be a fair bit of work, and not look like the result of Excel's PDF conversion. (Unless you put in yet more work to achieve identical results.)

Comment: Save to temp file, convert, remove temp file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Therefore, I am using the function **xlWorkSheet.PrintOut(Copies: 1, Preview: false, ActivePrinter: "PDFCreator", PrintToFile: true,PrToFileName: fullName);**   And the fullName has an extension ".pdf"..And the file is saved but it is unread...It is normal? Otherwise with **PrintToFile: false**, it works only when a window for saving the file pdf opens (I don't want it).

Comment: (if you don't write @ + a nick; nobody gets a warning when you answer) As explained, you cannot use any external program (with external I mean, anything different than the current Interop application), unless saving the file; PDFCreator is an external program and that's why you get a blank file. You can either use the suggestion in my link (Save it to PDF by using Interop instead of PDFCreator, via xlWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(etc.) or any of the other suggestions you have got (e.g., create the whole PDF from scratch or save a temp file). Next time, perhaps you should make an effort to...

Comment: ... understand the help you have got; or just ask the helpers further. Instead of continuing having the same ideas than before having got the help. Why are you asking, then? If you get worthy help and don't spend even one second in intending to understand this help, it is tiring for you (don't get your problem solved) and for the helpers who don't feel that their suggestions are even heard (well... read). I hope that now you have understood everything a bit better.

Comment: hey Varocarbas, thank you for your response (and sorry, I went too fast). You are right for your first comment, it is what I looked for (mainly in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407651(v=office.12).aspx ).